# Correct label syntax for JSON object

Tags: php, javascript, json, portability, jslint

It seems there are different standards out there on labels for JSON, some want quotes around JSON object labels, some do not.  Can someone tell me what the *standard* is?

### Quotes are bad camp

**Chrome**

`{"label":1111}` - *SyntaxError: Unexpected token :*

`{label:1111}` - *Works*

**Firefox**

`{"label":1111}` - *SyntaxError: invalid label*

`{label:1111}` - *Works*

### Quotes are good camp

**JSLint**

`{"video_id":1111}` - *JSON: good.*

`{video_id:1111}` - *JSON: bad.  Expected a string and instead saw* 'video_id'

**PHP**

```
echo json_encode(array('label' => 1111));
{"label":1111}
```

Comment: You want JSONLint, not JSLint.

Comment: If you look at the _result_ of `{label:1111}` in the console, you wouldn't say that.

Comment: Also: The standard is available on http://json.org, but to save you some reading, the standard requires quotes around labels.

Comment: WOW, I'd not realized there was a difference between Javascript objects and JSON.  Thanks everyone for the clarification!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The standard is to parse JSON as JSON.

The JSON language (unlike Javascript) always requires all property names to be surrounded by double-quotes.

Your syntax errors come from trying to parse JSON as Javascript *statements*.  The `{}` is parsed as a statement block, and the `label:` is parsed as a GOTO target.
Since statement labels cannot have quotes, this results in a syntax error.

If you wrap the JSON literals in parentheses to force Javascript to parse them as expressions,  you won't get that error.

Comment: +1 was just coming to the statement conclusion, albeit more slowly :-)

Comment: As a clarification, you should always parse json with  ```JSON.parse()``` - eval and injection is unsafe. As SLaks says, you're getting errors because of the ```{}``` being seen as a statement/scope block.